# AutoIncrement with Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables quiz in `quizId`  is the primary key.I have set it to auto_increment .I have another table quizQuestions in which i want the quizID of quiz table as the foriegn key.
These are the queries:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz (
      quizId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      subject varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      examDate date DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (quizId)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quizQuestions
    (
      quizId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      questionId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      question varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      option1 varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      option2 varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      option3 varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      option4 varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      answer varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,  
      PRIMARY KEY (questionId),
      Foreign Key (quizId) references quiz(quizId)
    )
```

NOw i want to ask that is my first line correct in quizQuestions, should i specify quizId as AUTO_INCREMENT in quizQuestions table also as quizId is a primary key of quiz table?

Comment: No...you do not require `AUTO_INCREMENT` on `quizId` in `quizQuestions` table as you are explicitly creating a relationship...which is probably also what you want as I understand from your schema... However if you are anticipating 1-to-many relationship...then you might want to consider using `AUTO_INCREMENT` on some other attribute to distinguish multiple children for this `quizQuestions` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quizId should not be auto_increment, and in this case it will not compile since it is not the primary key. As commented, since you are creating one-to-many relationship, you should make the quizId foreign key and the questionId auto increment primary key (as you did).

Note that if you make quizId both primary and foreign you can make it also auto increment, but this is not what you want....